# Problem with FTP import in V10

Tags: import, version-10

*Mathematica* V10 returns an error  when download directory.

> URLFetch :: invhttp: "FTP: could not retrieve (RETR failed) the specified file."

V9 successfully retrieves the same reference.
This code successful:
`Import["ftp://source:get@ftp.palemoon.org/integrated_statusbar-3.0.zip"]`
But this failed:
`Import["ftp://source:get@ftp.palemoon.org/"]`

Comment: Import[ftp://Login:Password@HOST/]

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: Importing from FTP works for me in version 10 under Windows; example: `Import["ftp://source:get@ftp.palemoon.org/integrated_statusbar-3.0.zip"]`

Comment: Your link my works too. But if you try to `Import[("ftp://source:get@ftp.palemoon.org/")]` then returns the same error as I

Comment: @Kypaku Do I understand that getting a directory list is what fails in v10, but this worked in v9?  If that is the case please update your question to state this and I shall reopen it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i updated question.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior.